# How to prevent variable being treated like a string?

Tags: jquery

I must target specific `label` element using its `for` parameter, and I must do it in a `forEach` cycle, like this:

```
 var iw_signup_tooltip = function(elements) {
     elements.forEach(function(entry) {
         $('<i class="icon"></i>').appendTo($('label[for=entry]'));
       }
     }
```

And then I'm calling it like this:

```
var elements = ['label1', 'label2'];
iw_signup_tooltip(elements);
```

But for some reason function fails and doesn't attach anything. But if I manually replace entry with 'label1' for example it works fine. Or even if I put label1 without `''` it will still work, so I guess there could be a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Something like `'label[for=' + entry+ ']'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatentation! You need to write the `entry` variable in - it won't be picked up automatically.

```
 $('<i class="icon"></i>').appendTo($('label[for=' + entry + ']'));
```

Comment: yep, but why I even need to do that, is it a bug in jQuery?

Comment: @Tachi this is pretty common for most programming languages.  When you declare a string like: 'this is a variable name: entry' the code does not know that you want the variable value and not just the word 'entry'.  By breaking the string with the quote and inserting the value of entry into the string, the string will know that you want the variables value instead of simple the word 'entry'.